# date & time script - ie vs ff

Tags: javascript, datetime

My script below works in ie but in firefox I get:

```
Mon, July 16th 2012 //this is ok

NaN:NaN:NaN (UTC +2) //but the time???
```

...

```
var weekdaystxt = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

function showLocalTime(container, servermode, offsetMinutes, displayversion) {
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
    this.container = document.getElementById(container)
    this.displayversion = displayversion
    var servertimestring = (servermode == "server-php") ? '<? print date("D, F jS Y H:i:s", time())?>' : (servermode == "server-ssi") ? '<!--#config timefmt="%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->' : '<%= Now() %>'
    this.localtime = this.serverdate = new Date(servertimestring)
    this.localtime.setTime(this.serverdate.getTime() + offsetMinutes * 60 * 1000) //add user offset to server time 
    this.updateTime()
    this.updateContainer()
}
showLocalTime.prototype.updateTime = function() {
    var thisobj = this
    this.localtime.setSeconds(this.localtime.getSeconds() + 1)
    setTimeout(function() {
        thisobj.updateTime()
    }, 1000) //update time every second 
}
showLocalTime.prototype.updateContainer = function() {
    var thisobj = this
    if (this.displayversion == "long") this.container.innerHTML = '<? print date("D, F jS Y")?>'
    else {
        var hour = this.localtime.getHours()
        var minutes = this.localtime.getMinutes()
        var seconds = this.localtime.getSeconds()
        var ampm = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"
        var dayofweek = weekdaystxt[this.localtime.getDay()]
        this.container.innerHTML = formatField(hour, 1) + ":" + formatField(minutes) + ":" + formatField(seconds) + " (UTC +2)"
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        thisobj.updateContainer()
    }, 1000) //update container every second 
}

function formatField(num, isHour) {
    if (typeof isHour != "undefined") { //if this is the hour field 
        var hour = (num > 24) ? num - 24 : num
        return (hour == 0) ? 24 : hour
    }
    return (num <= 9) ? "0" + num : num //if this is minute or sec field 
}
```

Comment: except he has dynamically generated JS produced from PHP (bleuch)

Comment: @Truth whenever the solution is correct I accept... If is left in the middle I cannot.. :) so I should change the code for date and time???

Comment: If you give me an email address I can send you a bunch of semicolons. I have lots of extras I will probably never use.

Answer (score 1):

First off, here's a jsFiddle of the code you posted so we can all see what's going on -

http://jsfiddle.net/HjDds/

Please note that this is a working version. The problem is with the different ways IE and Chrome parse dates. Whatever <% Now() %> was coming back as, Chrome did not like it and was not able to parse when creating the new Date() object.

You will need to make sure your server is sending back a date string that's in a format that will work crossbrowser.

As for my fix (though it's not really a fix since you seem to want server time) was to replace <%= Now() %> inside your servertimestring string with new Date(). I also added semi-colons since I also had a bunch of extras laying around.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Format Data: Mon, July 16th 2012 17:02:32

Php to use $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_TIME'] and multiply by 1000.

This would:

```
var servertimestring = (servermode == "server-php") ? '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']*1000;?>' : (servermode == "server-ssi") ? '<!--#config timefmt="%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->' : '<%= Now() %>';
```

:)